# Clone a div and then clone again from the child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following simple code, where I double click a div (with class **container**) and it's simply clones itself inside another div (with id **containment-wrapper**):

**html**

```
<span class="container">div one</span>

<div id="containment-wrapper">
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".container").dblclick(function() {

        $(this).clone().appendTo('#containment-wrapper');
});
```

When I double click the original div, it clones itself and puts a div inside the containment-wrapper but when I double click a cloned div, it doesn't do anything even though it has class=container, why is this happening? I tried many different ways to clone it but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the event handler isn't cloned. Use `delegate` instead:

```
$(".container").delegate("","dblclick",function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo('#containment-wrapper');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because dblclick is not bounded to the new div. What you want to achieve can be easily done with [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(".container").live('dblclick', function() {

        $(this).clone().appendTo('#containment-wrapper');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dynamically adding div tags they aren't automatically bound to the .dblclick function you've specified.  Using a [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler is one way to solve this.